# running java program from command line with classpath

Tags: java

Most of the time when i am learning something i am running java program from commandline.

now my problem is little complecated.

i am running Simple java program from command line. But i need CLASSPATH variable in environment variables. when i am adding CLASSPATH variable my program is giving me error.
The error is classNOtFoundException. Means when i am running program it will check .class file and it is going in my classpath variable and that is obvious it will not found and it will fire exception. 
i am always working line this. this problem occurs after i have formatted my PC. but i am using same OS and same jdk as it was.

Any body have faced this type of issue?
it is not working with following Screen shot.
[image]
[image]

Working with following screen shot
[image]

Following is my desktop screen shot and all things are working with classpath and without classpath(Means i can run simple Program no matter if classpath is there or not.).

[image]

Comment: The environment variable CLASSPATH that you show in your screenshot is the correct one to set.  Verify that the class that you are trying to find should in fact be in one of the paths listed in CLASSPATH.  Did you forget to re-install a library perhaps?

Comment: i am not understand what you are saying. we need CLASSPATH when we need to access classes from external jar. i am just running simple program in my D:. when i am compiling program it is making class file. and it will going to run if my classpath is not set. when i am adding classpath(for external jar like jdbc connector) i am getting classnotfound exception.

Comment: One most impostant thing is that is working with my Desktop. both have windows 7. desktop has 32 bit and my laptop has 64 bit.

Comment: Changes made to your system properties only affect *new* DOS windows. Are you opening a new window *after* making the changes to the environment variable?

Comment: you should *NEVER* set a OS wide classpath as listed in the screen shot. You should supply a classpath when you run your program with `java -cp classpathgoeshere Main` Setting a system wide classpath is very brittle and causes lots of subtle mis-behaviors.

Comment: i set there because there are nine jars to add in classpath. but if i will do that the again it will go in listed classpath and fire same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**1.** Goto your JDK folder, and then go inside bin,

**2.** Copy the path

eg: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin`

**3.** Paste this path in **"PATH",  NOT  "CLASSPATH"** .

**4.** Then i recommend giving the command "gpupdate /force" in cmd.

```
(I know it about updating policies, but that how it works for me....)
```

**5.** Then type the command **"java -version"** on cmd, if you get the jdk version in respose, you are good to go.

Comment: i know it is working without classpath environment variable. but what if i need to access classes from extrnal jar. at that time i have to define CLASSPATH. and wheni will define this thing will stop working.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin. is already in my path variable. thats why i can compile java program. Problem when i am using folloeing command java myclass.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "." (current directory) to your system class path.

A better practice would be to create a batch file to set per-application environment variables and launch your program.

---

Please include the full text of the class not found exception and the system class path you have defined.

Comment: but the same thing is working with my desktop. i know it will create same problem when i will put CLASSPATH. and i am working with Hibernate so i need add jar files in my classpath.

Answer (score 0):

According to you your `JDK` is working properly (because u getting `classNOtFoundException`)
so defiantly the class which you want to run is not in class path
Lets try this..

```
java -cp /your/path  ClassName
```

Other wise Lets  take a look of this may its  helps you..  [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: ok. So that same thing is working with my desktop. ? i am saying that it is working with my Desktop then why not with my laptop. and i was working before i formatted my laptop.